# Return Google Desktop version with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

How could I do to get the Google Desktop Version with Scrapy?

The issue is this:
When you scrapy to google, it returns the mobile version. So, I set up an user agent, but now returns a weird html, like the mobile version.

```
import scrapy

class Searcher(scrapy.Spider):
    name='rast'
    start_urls=[
        'https://google.com/search?q=lawyers'
    ]
    user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'

    def parse(self, response):
        data={}

        body=response.css('div').getall()
        
        data['body']=body
        
        yield data
```

With Selenium/Requests, it's easy, but I've reading that the right way to **scrape** websites is with Scrapy.

And BTW, the reason I need the Desktop Version is because Google gives some bold terms called variations to the keywords.

Thank you!

Comment: maybe use different `user agent` - maybe some from Windows, not Macintosh, and without Safari and/or AppleWebKit

Comment: you can see your browser USER AGENT on [http://www.useragentstring.com/](http://www.useragentstring.com/). There is also [list from other computers and programs](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php)

Comment: Thank you guys. I've tried with my own user agent, and even from windows, and it doesn't work =/

Comment: It can check other elements in browser. For example Google sends different HTML when you turn off JavaScript in browser. You may have to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser - with running JavaScript and other elements.